# pgfplots: xticklabels and yticklabels in fractions

Tags: pgfplots

How to properly put xticklabels and yticklabels in fractions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\let\ds\displaystyle

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\large $x$},
    ylabel={\large $y$},
    xticklabel style={inner xsep=0pt, anchor=south west},
    yticklabel style={inner ysep=0pt, anchor=south west},
    xtick={-0.5,2},
    ytick={-0.25},
    yticklabels={$\ds -\frac{1}{4}$},
    xticklabels={$\ds -\frac{1}{2}$,$2$},
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=6,
    xmin=-5,
    xmax=5,
    samples=50
]
\addplot[color=blue,thick] {(x + 1 / 2) / (x - 2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Once you make your code a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages, and  define what `\ds` is, your example shows the tick labels as you specified.  Perhaps you have some older packages.

Comment: \let\ds\displaystyle

Comment: So then your code seems to work. What exactly is the problem with the image you have? Also, please make your code a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is

```
xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,frac,frac TeX=\ds\frac,frac denom=2},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,frac,frac TeX=\ds\frac,frac denom=4},
```

for x ticks with denominator 2 and y ticks with denominator 4. `frac TeX` accepts the macro to use for typesetting the fraction—I've added your `\ds` directive here.

This method is mentioned briefly in the [`pgfplots` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots), where the reader is referred to the [`pgfplotstable` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) for the full detail.

I also adjusted the alignment/padding of the tick labels to minimize clashes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\let\ds\displaystyle

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    axis lines=middle,
    inner axis line style={=>},
    xlabel={\large $x$},
    ylabel={\large $y$},
    xticklabel style={inner xsep=0pt, anchor=north east},
    yticklabel style={inner xsep=0pt, anchor=south east},
    xtick={-0.5,2},
    ytick={-0.25},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,frac,frac TeX=\ds\frac,frac denom=2},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,frac,frac TeX=\ds\frac,frac denom=4},
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=6,
    xmin=-5,
    xmax=5,
    samples=50
]
\addplot[color=blue,thick] {(x + 1 / 2) / (x - 2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]